# crmlistcomponent.wsp problem while Upgrading?

Tags: 2013, workflow, upgrade, crm

I want to upgrade SharePoint 2010 site to  2013 using content database attach Method. but I have " crmlistcomponent.wsp " installed in SharePoint 2010 farm. my questions are

1)it can cause any problem if I do direct Content Database attach or I have to install crmlistcomponent.wsp again in  2013 farm?

2.There are some Workflows in 2010.will they cause any problem?

Answer (score 0):

The general approach is to deploy the SP 2010 WSPs to SP 2013 farm after restoring content database using database attach method. At this point the SP 2013 site should run properly in SP 2010 mode. After this you need to perform the upgrade to SP 2013 and re-deploy the WSP file after converting them properly to be compatible with SP 2013.

**Custom workflow activities**: For SharePoint 2010 custom activities to work in SharePoint 2013, the “authorizedType” node needs to be defined in a new sub-section “targetFx” under the “authorizedTypes” section in web.config file.

Similarly, to convert SP 2010 solutions to SP 2013, you need to update Dot Net Framework to 4.5, Assembly versions to 15.0.0.0, references of `/_layouts/` to `/_layouts/15/` and reference of `~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES` to `~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/15` etc. If you have laatest version of VS 2012/2013 and office developer tools installed many of these things will be automatically done by Visual Studio. For more information see:
http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2013/12/sharepoint-2013-upgrade-from-sharepoint.html
http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2013/12/sharepoint-2013-upgrade-sharepoint-2010.html